# MySQL columns for time tracker app

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a personal time tracker web app. I'm going have a start, pause and finished buttons on the page to update/create rows in a database. It's built in PHP.

I have: id, user_id, project, notes, created, updated.

I'm wondering what is the best methods to allow people to pause and resume their tasks to get a total time for one task (with all pauses minussed).

What column types and attributes should i set on the columns and what is my best method of updating said columns?

Comment: Given that your data set is naturally 1:n (1 user with potentially unlimited pause-starts), the obviously design is to store the pause/unpause times in a child table.

Comment: How much granularity are you going to need?  Do you want to have a record, say, that User A paused at 12:00, 2:00, and 2:15?  Or does only total time elapsed matter?

Comment: Hmmm, i think total time lapsed is the only one i'd care about. So user A - 26th Aug 2011 - project B - 26 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created such an app also, in a distant past, in C#. Seems like everybody needs one and the employer does not provide it :-)

On topic, please consider just breaking the task when somebody pauses a task. So actually end the task in the backend. When resuming the task, just start a new task in the backend. On rollup, collect adjacent tasks with same task_id as a single task. Doing this, you might want to apply restrictions on the task duration; split up over day boundaries, have a max time between tasks to call it one task etc. This way you are very flexible dealing with your task **Smart** on the backend, while your front end is actually based on a simplified model.